# python numpy convert data errors

Tags: python

to read data from a mysql table , and use numpy to transfer the data to numpy array, the data in the mysql table include varchar(128),int, bigint,float, therefore, I think I may read these data all as string type at first, try using numpy.fromiter:

```
select_sql = "select * from fb_web_active_group_members_user_mbkmeansclustering_ng_six_test"
count = cur.execute(select_sql)
if count:
    user_level_cluster_data = cur.fetchall()
    user_level_cluster_data_df = numpy.fromiter(user_level_cluster_data,dtype = numpy.str,count = -1)
```

but it errors:

```
File "F:/MyDocument/F/My Document/Training/Python/PyCharmProject/FaceBookCrawl/FB_group_user_stability.py", line 21, in get_pre_new_user_level_data
user_level_cluster_data_df = numpy.fromiter(user_level_cluster_data,dtype = numpy.str,count = -1)
ValueError: Must specify length when using variable-size data-type.
```

could you please tell me the reason and how to resolve it, if I want read all the data from the mysql table as their own data types(not read them all as string type at first), such as: the varchar(128) data as string, int type as int, float type as float....how I should do

Comment: I think better is [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) here.

Answer (score 1):

`dtype` needs to be the entire, full dtype for a whole record.  Your current error occurs because NumPy strings are fixed-capacity, so you'd need to say `dtype='S128'` for example, to get strings up to 128 characters in capacity.  But your actual dtype probably consists of several columns, so you might want something like this:

```
dtype=[('colA', 'i4'), ('colB', 'f8'), ('colC', 'S128')]
```

Also note that `fromiter()` may not be helping you, since you're using `fetchall()` which I think returns a list anyway.  You can simply do:

```
np.array(user_level_cluster_data, dtype)
```

Or if you want to use `fromiter()`, you should pass it the `count` parameter and use lazy fetching instead of `fetchall()`.