# Array of strings from dict iterable: what dtype to use?

Tags: python, string, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary structured as so:

```
mydict = {'Sample1': ['0|0','0|1','0|0'],
          'Sample2': ['0|0','1|1','0|0'],
          'Sample3': ['0|1','0|1','1|0'] }
```

I'd like to convert it to an array like this one :

```
myarray = [['0|0','0|1','0|0'],
           ['0|0','1|1','0|0'],
           ['0|1','0|1','1|0']]
```

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24885203/3575623) that `np.fromiter` is the function I should use, but I'm struggling with the `dtype`.

`myarray = np.fromiter(mydict.values(), dtype=str)` gives me the error "ValueError: Must specify length when using variable-size data-type."

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47157600/3575623) that the notation 'Sfoo' allows you to specify that you are using only strings of length foo, but when I try `myarray = np.fromiter(mydict.values(), dtype='S3)`, it yields this error, which I am struggling to solve: "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just unpack the dictionary values and pass it to `np.array`, you will get the array you are looking for.

```py
>>> np.array([*mydict.values()])
array([['0|0', '0|1', '0|0'],
       ['0|0', '1|1', '0|0'],
       ['0|1', '0|1', '1|0']], dtype='<U3')
```

Another approach might be to use `np.char.encode` and pass the unpacked values in the dictionary if you want the dtype to be `S3` which is typically the byte string representation where 3 denotes the length.

```py
>>> np.char.encode([*mydict.values()])
array([[b'0|0', b'0|1', b'0|0'],
       [b'0|0', b'1|1', b'0|0'],
       [b'0|1', b'0|1', b'1|0']], dtype='|S3')
```

Comment: Trying this out now, seems to be working. What does the * before mydict do?

Comment: `[*mydict.values()]` will basically create a list out of all the values in the dictionary, it is called values unpacking and is same as `list(mydict.values())`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `numpy` for that, you can simply do

```
myarray = list(mydict.values())
```